# Adobe Flash CS3 Profesional - missing DirectShow 9 and QuickTime 7

Tags: flash, encoding, flv, flash-cs3

In Adobe Flash CS3 Profesional and when I start
 the Flash Video Encoder I get the following message: 
 "A required system library did not initialize properly. Please ensure you 
 have DirectShow 9 and QuickTime 7 or higher installed on your system."

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DirectShow 9 and QuickTime 7 or higher installed on your system?

Comment: I did. And it worked. I wanted to answer my own Q. You were faster:D Thx.

Answer (score 0):

1] Download and install the latest DirectX.

2] Confirm the version, enter "dxdiag" in run prompt.
Diagnostic Tool will open. Under "Display 1" (and "Display 2" if you have dual monitor) tab, check that "Direct Draw acceleration" and "Direct Draw 3D" is enabled. You can also run some tests. In notes box see potential errors.

3] Download and install QuickTime or if you don't like bloat - [QuickTime Alternative](http://www.free-codecs.com/download/QuickTime_Alternative.htm)

4] Restart and enjoy working Adobe Flash Encoder.

(tested on WIN XP Pro)